# I have created a glove on Blender and I want to apply Voronoi on it's surface via Sverchok. How can I do that?

Tags: texturing, sverchok

How can I apply Voronoi 3d in a model/object that I have created in Blender. I have created a glove and I want to apply Voronoi as a texture on its surface through Sverchok.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear to me what is `texture` for you (image or image' geometry representation)
import this node tree in sverchok with import panel (copy link)
https://gist.github.com/86bc3942e438f8b78313afa21858daad
[image]